# placeholder showing cs0103

Tags: c#, html

My place holder in the C# part is coming up with a cs0103 and i cant figure out why. im trying to put data into a table in the html portion and was using a place holder. but it seems to be having an issue with my place holder  id placeholder1. can any one see the issue im running into

Here Is my HTML

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="AdventureWorks.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Adventure Works Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<img class="banner" src="Images/AdvWorksBanner.png" alt="Adventure Works"/>
<div class="title"><img class="imgleft" src="Images/trainer_red.png" /><img class="imgright" src="Images/trainer_red.png" />Products Page</div>
<div class="nav">
    <button type="button" onclick="location.href='home.aspx'" class="button">Home</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="location.href='about.aspx'" class="button">About</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="location.href='products.aspx'" class="button">Products</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="location.href='Login.aspx'" class="button">Login</button>
</div>
<div>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID = "PlaceHolder1" runat ="server"/>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the C#

```
namespace AdventureWorks
{

public partial class Products : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            //Populating a DataTable from database.
            DataTable dt = this.GetData();

            //Building an HTML string.
            StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

            //Table start.
            html.Append("<table border = '1'>");

            //Building the Header row.
            html.Append("<tr>");
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                html.Append("<th>");
                html.Append(column.ColumnName);
                html.Append("</th>");
            }
            html.Append("</tr>");

            //Building the Data rows.
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                html.Append("<tr>");
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {
                    html.Append("<td>");
                    html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                    html.Append("</td>");
                }
                html.Append("</tr>");
            }

            //Table end.
            html.Append("</table>");

            //Append the HTML string to Placeholder.
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });
        }
    }
        private DataTable GetData()
        {
            using (var connection = Functions.AdventureWorks())
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name, ListPrice FROM Production.Product where ListPrice Is Not Null and ListPrice != 0;"))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = connection;
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            sda.Fill(dt);
                            return dt;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `PlaceHolder1` is not declared anywhere. Side point: that is really not the way to construct HTML

Comment: Your aspx specifies Codebehind=Home.aspx.cs, but your C# class is Products?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing i forgot to change the title from my master page

Comment: @Charlieface what do you mean thats not how i should construct my html? very curious cause im trying to get into application development and this is for my portfolio but i havent done programming since college 5 years ago and trying to freshen  up and create portfolio for my resume. and i fixed my placeholder issue

Comment: FYI Webforms is "old tech", try and read up on MVC and Razor

Comment: You should create HTML using a proper serializer like `XDocument` or HTMLAgilityPack, rather than just concatenating it yourself (which is likely to cause escaping errors and more)

Comment: User GridView for showing data in tabular format... but it is better to learn ASP.NET MVC then working on old webforms.